# Alignment on two rows in display flex

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to pass the last two items over each other as shown on the bottom of this photo.
[image]
Is this possible as is by forcing a line break or do I have to change the display of the parent div?

The HTML structure looks like this :

```
<div class="wp-block-cover">
    <ul class="articleslisteshp" id="lcp_instance_0">
        <li>
            <a>Lorem ipsum article title</a>
            <span class="testcat" style="width: 100%;">
                <a>Category1</a>
                <a>Category2</a> 
            </span>

            <a><img width="150" height="150"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Et voici le CSS que j'ai essayé :

```
ul.articleslisteshp{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

ul.articleslisteshp > li{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take out the a tag from inside the list if possible and put it outside of it. Like so:

```
<div class="wp-block-cover">
    <ul class="articleslisteshp" id="lcp_instance_0">
        <a><img width="150" height="150"></a>
        <li>
            <a>Lorem ipsum article title</a>
            <span class="testcat" style="width: 100%;">
                <a>Category1</a>
                <a>Category2</a> 
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And use the following CSS to achieve what you asked for:

```
ul.articleslisteshp{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

ul.articleslisteshp > li{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

span.testcat {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```